# Ajahn Tong has deviated from the main point of Mahasi Sayadaw's meditation technique?

Tags: untagged

I have heard the claim that Ajahn Tong deviated from the main point of Mahasi Sayadaw's meditation technique and he taught it as a concentration technique. I don't understand how that could be. Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu isn't teaching concentration meditation and he is Ajahn Tong's student. Does anyone know why anyone would make this claim? As I understand, Ajahn Tong was pretty strict about not practicing just concentration meditation.

Comment: " Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu isn't teaching concentration meditation" I Think you have this wrong, Yuttadhammo does not teach SAMATHA, tranquil meditation. His technique is solely focused on satipathana/vipassana.

Comment: I know that. But that is the claim. Can you believe it? Some people are going around thinking Ajahn Tong is teaching concentration. It blows my mind how anyone could think that.

Comment: He IS teaching concentration meditation, sattipathanna and vipassana. Satipathanna is concentration, vipassana insight/wisdom.

Comment: I agree with you but the claim is or the implication is that Ajahn Tong deviated from Satipathanna to teach concentration only, he didn't teach enough Satipathana  or something like that. I don't really know exactly what they mean, that is why I am asking. I saw someone in a Vipassana forum state this but that forum is closed. Then I saw the same critique elsewhere too. I was blown away that people could think that. How could they possibly come to that conclusion? That is the opposite of reality.

Comment: @Remyla Perhaps you meant Samatha? Satipathana is not a concentration meditation, the term is often used interchangeably with Vipassana. Satipatthana Sutta was the foundation of all Burmese "Vipassana" teachers, including Mahasi Sayadaw. 
By the way he style that Mahasi was teaching also developed concentration to an extent, because his main meditation object was rising and falling of abdomen, which naturally leads to concentration. Hence Vipassana Jhanas that eg U Pandita (another Mahasi student) was talking about.